# Various problems with Python installations: No module named pip3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, installation

I have been attempting to set up Python on my Windows and it has been a nightmare (my only programming experience has been with R and ImageJ macros). After endless Googling I managed to use pip to set up all the image processing libraries I need but now I hit another rock - with pip3.
I have to install Pytorch for a course I am attending tonight and using the line from online:

```
pip3 install torch==1.2.0+cpu torchvision==0.4.0+cpu -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

I get ... nothing. The cmd just stays unresponsive, like it is waiting for an input or just loading something, and it never loads anything. 
As a matter of fact I get the exact same result when I try to use pip to install. Pretty much any command I type starting with pip leads to this result (unresponsiveness from cmd), including *pip list*. So this line:

```
python -m pip install <...>
```

is the only way I managed to install anything using pip. 
When I tried to use this same trick with pip3:

```
python -m pip3 install torch==1.2.0+cpu torchvision==0.4.0+cpu -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

I get:

> C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe: No
>   module named pip3

But pip3 very much exists in the Scripts folder, and this shows when I type in

```
where pip3
```

in the command window - it gives the directory as it should.

I am at an absolute loss, especially since I have to have this installed by tonight and there is not much information about pip3 issues specifically (and pip finally works fine for me).. 
Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: `pip3` == `pip` but for Python3. Check your your pip version using `pip --version` - if it's pip for python3, all `pip3` commands you see are just `pip` commands for you.

Comment: there is no module `pip3` - only `pip`. `pip3` means you install for python 3, not python 2. If you have `python3.exe` then you can try `python3 -m pip` instead of `python -m pip` but normally you use only `python -m pip`. On Linux you could have files `pip`, `pip2`, `pip2.7`, `pip3`, `pip3.6`, `pip3.7` to easily install module in prefered Python

Comment: Ah, makes sense, so typing: `python -m pip install torch==1.2.0+cpu torchvision==0.4.0+cpu -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html` did the job perfectly, thank you loads. Is there a way to mark comments as solution to the problem?